# Pattern search and next line copy

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
AAA
DDD
EEE
```

It has a specific keyword, for example `AAA`. After encountering the keyword, I'd like to copy the following line and then write it a second time in my output file.

I want it to look like this:

```
AAA
BBB
BBB
CCC
AAA
DDD
DDD
EEE
```

Is there anybody who will help me to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Sed can do it like this:

```
$ sed '/AAA/{n;p}' infile
AAA
BBB
BBB
CCC
AAA
DDD
DDD
EEE
```

This looks for the pattern (`/AAA/`), the reads the next line of input (`n`) and prints it (`p`). Because printing is the default action anyway, the line gets printed twice, which is what we want.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'd{print;d=0} /AAA/{d=1}1' file

AAA
BBB
BBB
CCC
AAA
DDD
DDD
EEE
```

**Explanation**

`d{print;d=0}`
if flag `d`set print the line and reset the flag,

`/AAA/{d=1}`
set a flag to duplicate the line for the given pattern,

`1`
and print all lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl for this

```
perl -e ' $a =undef;
          while(<>){
              chomp;
              if ($a eq "AAA"){
                  print "$_\n"
                 }
              print "$_\n";
              $a=$_;
              }' your_file.txt
```

This iterates through the file and prints each line. If the previous line is "AAA", it prints it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you share my hatred of one-line programs, but this is entirely possible in Perl

```
$ perl -ne'print; print scalar <> x 2 if /AAA/' aaa.txt
```

#### output

```
AAA
BBB
BBB
CCC
AAA
DDD
DDD
EEE
```